What does ほど means after a noun used like this?
"いじめられたことがあるんですか?"
"……"
"自分と一緒ですね"
少し背が高いだけで、少し目線が合わないだけで。
臆病な人ほど、石を投げる。
The character are sharing their experience being bullied... as far I can tell he's saying coward people threw rock over being a bit taller etc but what does ほど here mean? would が work?

This question is similar to: ほど translation in this sentence. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
